# Optimising a sql correlated subquery statement

Tags: optimization, index

I am updating a column on tableA with data from tableB like this:

```
update tableA
  set bKey = select bKey from tableB B where B.colB = tableA.colB
```

bKey has a unique index on tableB.

Which is the better optimisation for this query, indexing tableB on ColB or (ColB,bKey) and why?

I am interested in answers for any database.

Answer (score 2):

**Neither.**

Index `ColB INCLUDE (bKey)`

Since you aren't filtering on `bKey` you don't need it at all the nodes of the index, just the leaf level.

If you only index on `ColB` then you will still have to pay for a key lookup to get the value of `bKey` from the clustered index.

Also is there a reason this isn't using a `JOIN` instead of a correlated subquery?

```
UPDATE a
SET a.bKey = b.bKey
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON A.ColB = B.ColB
```

Comment: The join is interesting - why would the optimiser do better with the join?. Is it because you've specified 'inner' rather than 'left'?

Comment: @Stora - no, but depending on the implementation of SQL (sql server, MySQL, etc) and version the subquery may be executed once per row instead of as a set, while the `JOIN` will always be a set-based operation.